# Calculus: What to do when algebraically stuck, when trying to resolve an equation to find critical point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

My understanding:

- g'(x) & g(x) are defined for all real numbers.
- However I think I'm confused when I equate $e^{3x}(1+3x)=0$, I'm trying to solve for $e^{3x}=0$ after dividing both sides by $(1+3x)=0$ algebraically. I'm stuck as there is no value of x in $e^{3x}$ that is zero. What do I do next?

[image]

Comment: Why do you claim that $g(x)$ is a polynomial? (It isn't.) And why do you claim that $g'(0)$ is undefined? (Again, it isn't.)

Comment: What? $g'(x) = e^{3x} (1+3x)$, so $g'(0) = 1$, since $e^0 = 1$. That has nothing to do with $e^{3x}$ being nonzero. Perhaps you confuse $g'(0)$ with the solutions to $g'(x) = 0$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I see, apologies I mean that g(x) is defined at all values. I see now that I've got the polynomial definition wrong.

Comment: @MartinR, yea it seems like I did.. So all values of g'(x) are defined if i don't equate it to zero. I think I'm confused when I equate $e^{3x}(1+3x)=0$, I'm trying to solve for $e^{3x}=0$ after dividing both sides by $(1+3x)=0$ algebraically. I'm stuck as there is no value of x in $e^{3x}$ that is zero

Comment: Exactly, there are no $x$ values that make $e^{3x}=0$. But there are $x$ values that make $1+3x = 0$, which give you a critical value. But $x=0$ is not a critical value, because $g^{\prime}(0)$ is defined and nonzero.

Comment: So when there are no values that make $e^{3x}=0$, we should.. ignore it? I guess I mechanically marked it as undefined as I can't solve for it. What is the correct next step or conclusion to make here when i can't resolve the alegbra?

Comment: Yes, since $e^{3x}$ is never 0, you can divide it out to get $1+3x=0$. The fact that $e^{3x}(1+3x) = 0$ means either $e^{3x} = 0$ (no $x$-values fall into this category) or $(1+3x) = 0$ (you can find an $x$-value meeting this condition).

Comment: Ok, so we basically ignore the $e^{3x}=0$ part of the equation if there's no solution isn't it basically undefined for 0? (even though there is a solution at x=0, which is 1). I get that if it's a rule but it's hard to logically accept that I should just ignore the equation. // Using a seperate example when I encounter $x=\sqrt-4$, I know for a fact there's no real solution and undefined. Perhaps my gap here is that i'm mixing up undefined and having no real solution..?

Comment: Determine critical points which are points where $f'(x) = 0$ or where $f'(x)$ does not exist. The factor $e^{3x}$ provides no critical points, so the only critical point is $x = -1/3.$ Thus, in your first derivative sign chart, only one point is marked. Determine the signs of the factors in the intervals formed by the critical points. The factor $e^{3x}$ is positive at each point, so you have all plus signs. The factor $(1 + 3x)$ changes sign at $x = -1/3$ --- negative to left, positive to right. See [these detailed examples](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/TpC_fn-MkU4/m/QW0IXAWhqf4J).

Answer (score -1):

No. In particular, we clearly have $g'(0) = e^{3\times 0}(1 + 3 \times 0) = e^0(1 + 0) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you. I see that actually, g'(x) is defined for all values. I think I'm confused when I equate $e^{3x}(1+3x)=0$, I'm trying to solve for $e^{3x}=0$ after dividing both sides by $(1+3x)=0$ algebraically. I'm stuck as there is no value of x in $e^{3x}$ that is zero. Is it a mistake to divide both sides to try and find other values for x?

Comment: @olif9837 It doesn't make sense to "divide by $(1+3x) = 0$". You can divide by $(1+3x)$, but only if you assume that $(1+3x) \neq 0$.

Comment: You aren't trying to "equate $e^{3x}(1 + 3x) = 0$. You're trying to evaluate $g'(0)$. Even if you were trying to solve $e^{3x}(1 + 3x) = 0$, you wouldn't want to divide by $(1 + 3x)$: as you note, that gives no solutions. You should instead divide by $e^{3x}$ to obtain $1 + 3x = 0$, and solve to give the unique zero of $x = \frac{-1}{3}$.

Comment: @user3482749, so we basically ignore the 3=0 part of the equation if there's no solution isn't it basically undefined for 0? (even though there is a solution at x=0, which is 1). I get that if it's a rule but it's hard to logically accept that I should just ignore the equation. // Using a seperate example when I encounter =−‾‾√4, I know for a fact there's no real solution and undefined. Perhaps my gap here is that i'm mixing up undefined and having no real solution..?

Comment: There *is* no "$e^{3x} = 0$ part" of the equation. Like, at all. That simply isn't an equation that you have written down, or an equation that you can derive from anything that you have written down.